# Regex to replace single or multiple occurrence of hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written below function to convert space with hyphen or reverse

1. space with hyphen `str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-')`
2. hyphen with space `str.replace(/\-/g,' ')`

But now I am trying to replace single hyphen with double hyphen, I can't use point 1 function because it convert single/multiple occurrence instead of single.

Is there any way to write regex which do 3 operation in single formula

1. convert forward slash with underscore `replace(/\//g, '_')`
2. convert space with single hyphen
3. convert single hyphen with multiple hyphen

e.g.
regex 1 change

```
"Name/Er-Gourav Mukhija" into "Name_Er--Gourav-Mukhija"
```

regex 2 do reverse of it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a callback function instead of a replace string. That way you can specify and replace all characters at once.

```js
const input = 'Name/Er-Gourav Mukhija';
const translate = {
  '/': '_',
  '-': '--',
  ' ': '-',
};
const reverse = {
  '_': '/',
  '--': '-',
  '-': ' ',
};

// This is just a helper function that takes
// the input string, the regex and the object
// to translate snippets.
function replaceWithObject( input, regex, translationObj ) {
  return input.replace( regex, function( match ) {
    return translationObj[ match ] ? translationObj[ match ] : match;
  } );
}

function convertString( input ) {
  // Search for /, - and spaces
  return replaceWithObject( input, /(\/|\-|\s)/g, translate );
}

function reverseConvertedString( input ) {
  // Search for _, -- and - (the order here is very important!)
  return replaceWithObject( input, /(_|\-\-|\-)/g, reverse );
}

const result = convertString( input );
console.log( result );
console.log( reverseConvertedString( result ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write a Regex formula which does conditional replacements (ie a->b, c->d).  I would instead try to create two statements to replace " " -> "--" and "/" -> "_".

You can use your existing code for both of these operations.  I would recommend using [this site](https://regexr.com/) for building and testing Regexes in the future.

Comment: Regexr has some issues withe the javascript regexp version. Better use [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `var str = "Name/Er-Gourav Mukhija"`

1. To convert forward slash with underscore, as you mentioned use `replace(/\//g, '_')`
2. To convert space with single hyphen, use `replace(/\s+/g, '-')`
3. To convert single hyphen to double hyphen, use `replace(/\-/g, '--')`.

All these 3 can be combined into:

`str.replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\-/g, '--')`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop to do all at once:

```
str = str.split("");
var newStr = "";
str.forEach(function (curChar) {
  switch(curChar) {
    case " ":
      newStr += "-";
      break;
    case "/":
      newStr += "_";
      break;
    case "-":
      newStr += "--";
      break;
    default:
      newStr += curChar;
  } 
});
str = newStr;
```

Feel free to turn this into a function if you like. I also havven't made it do the reverse, but all you'd need to do is replace the assignment strings with the case strings in the switch () statement.

There's no way to do it all with regex, as your later regex will overwrite your first regex in at least one case no matter how you write it.